# How can you print multiple pages with different sizes?

Tags: css, printing

When you do something like

```
@page { size:8.5in 11in; margin: 2cm }
```

It affects all pages. Is there a way to have one page as a4, the other has a2, legal, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pseudo-classes:

- [@page :first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first) for the first page
- [@page :left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:left) allows to describe the styling of left-side pages
- [@page :right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:right) allows to describe the styling of right-side pages

But

> You can't change all CSS properties. You can only change the the `margin`, `padding`, `border`, and `background` properties of the page box. All other CSS properties will be ignored, and only the page box, not the document content on the page, will be affected.

Comment: This only changes the content inside, for example, 

http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/2wk6Q/1949/

I want the page1 to be legal and the page 2 to be letter when it runs.